# Get decimal value from a DWORD in the registry

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to retrieve de int value of this reg dword:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate

I'm able to retrieve a strings' value, but i cant get the int value of the dword...
At the end, i would like to have the install date of windows.
I searched an found some solutions, but none worked.

I'm starting with this:

```
public void setWindowsInstallDate()
{
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\NT\CurrentVersion");
    if (key != null)
    {
        object value = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
        // some extra code ??? ...
        WindowsInstallDate = value;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if that registry key is correct (typo?), but you would need to know how that `InstallDate` DWORD is formatted. But not sure what you mean by "decimal" of a DWORD. DWORDs are integer values.

Comment: You mean with the @? that works the same as ""SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\NT\\CurrentVersion"

Comment: If i open the dword via windows registry editor, i can choose to see the value as hex or decimal...

Comment: Its a System.Int32, it returns as 0

Comment: base 16 or base 10 ("decimal"), but c# has a `Decimal` class, and my reading of the question was that you wanted a value with decimal point (floating point value). As far as the registry key, "Windows NT" vs. "Windows\NT", perhaps?

Comment: Yes, i mean an int...

Comment: You should be able to cast the `Object` to the type that it is.

Comment: i can do this:
object value = key.GetValue("InstallDate");
string theValue = value.ToString();

but this turns out zero, 0

Comment: The problem is, after some testing,
How can i retrieve the hex value of a dword

Comment: do you have a 64 bit windows and compile your application with AnyCPU? Try project options -> build -> Platform target -> x64

Comment: Did you look at the value of `value` in the debugger? If it is `0` but you can go to that *exact* registry location and see something different, then something went wrong. Otherwise, the `value` should have what you need just cast to an integer type.

Comment: Use System.Management to do this, much safer and long term supported without surprises.  Query Win32_OperatingSystem for the InstallDate property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you have is an issue between the 32 bit registry view and the 64 bit registry view as described on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129.aspx).

To solve it you can do the following. Note that the returned value is a Unix timestamp (i.e. the number of seconds from 1 Jan 1970) so you need to manipulate the result to get the correct date:

```
//get the 64-bit view first
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

if (key == null)
{
    //we couldn't find the value in the 64-bit view so grab the 32-bit view
    key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
    key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
}

if (key != null)
{
    Int64 value = Convert.ToInt64(key.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString());
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    DateTime installDate = epoch.AddSeconds(value);
}
```

The return from `GetValue` is an `Object` but `AddSeconds` requires a numeric value so we need to cast the result. I could have used `uint` above as that's big enough to store the [DWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx#dword) which is (32 bits) but I went with `Int64`.

If you prefer it more terse you could rewrite the part inside the null check in one big line:

```
DateTime installDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
                      .AddSeconds(Convert.ToUInt32(key.GetValue("InstallDate")));
```

Comment: can you explain to me why you are doing this line of code: Int64 value = Convert.ToInt64(key.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString());

Answer (score -4):

It isn´t to hard to solve.
First of all - skip HKLM if using 64bit. (LocalMachine)
Use HKCU (CurrentUser)
Use a stringvalue instead of dword for a Installdate.
Get stringvalue from registry and then "parse" to DateTime.