# VB.Net Read DWORD from Registry

Tags: vb.net

How to Read DWORD from registry in VB.Net
I tired below code

```
Dim rk As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", False)

Dim registryValue As Int32 = CInt(rk.GetValue("InstallDate", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord))
```

But it always returns 0.

Comment: There may be a difference... are you sure it is not a string or a long?

Comment: Yes. It is DWORD, but in VB.net there is no data type like DWORD, so used Int32

Comment: I googled your problem, found on the first page not less than 6 solutions for your problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the install time and date of Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170617/how-do-i-find-the-install-time-and-date-of-windows)

Comment: I need other values from Registry. Only for example I have given it

Comment: The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912947/get-decimal-value-from-a-dword-in-the-registry) should work

Comment: I need solution in VB.net

Comment: Use [this site](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert C# to VB.NET ( It's easy to do that manually without sites too ).